# Flutter: how can use hooks to change the visibility of text in textformfield?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hooks

I'm trying to move my `TextFormField` logic to hooks but what I'm trying is doesn't seem to work.

my custom hook,

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

enum Index { email, password }

TextFormField useTextFormField(Index index) {
  return use(_CustomHook(index: index));
}

class _CustomHook extends Hook<TextFormField> {
  final Index index;
  _CustomHook({@required this.index});

  @override
  _CustomHookState createState() => _CustomHookState();
}

class _CustomHookState extends HookState<TextFormField, _CustomHook> {
  Index index;

  @override
  TextFormField build(BuildContext context) {
    final visible = useState(false);
   // useEffect((){
    //  print('in');
   //visible.value=!visible.value;
     // print(visible.value.toString());
     // return;
   // },const []);
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'some help',
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () { 
              visible.value = !visible.value;}, //<--- here
            icon: Icon(visible.value ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
          )),
      validator: (text) {
        if (text.isEmpty) return 'enter something';

        return null;
      },
      obscureText: index == Index.email ? visible.value : true,
    );
  }
}
```

i'm new to hooks and I don't know I can use `useState()` and `useEffect()`, if anyone can help